Finding crash in SwiftUI/SwiftData with Crashlytics Report when code lines don't match up
I've got a SwiftUI + SwiftData app and I'm trying to understand the crash reports I'm getting from Firebase Crashlytics.
Crash Report: closure #2 in closure #1 in closure #1 in RootContentView.body.getter
SIGABRT (ABORT)


Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0xc2d4 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x859c pthread_kill + 268
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x77b08 abort + 128
3  AttributeGraph                 0x12e94 <redacted> + 228
4  AttributeGraph                 0x11e40 <redacted> + 222
5  SwiftUICore                    0x80134 $s7SwiftUI9GraphHostC17flushTransactionsyyF + 292
6  SwiftUICore                    0x12fbe4 <redacted> + 616
...
9  libswiftObservation.dylib      0x777c <redacted> + 112
...
14 SwiftData                      0xd59d8 <redacted> + 43160
...
25 _SwiftData_SwiftUI             0x54e4 <redacted> + 1560
26 _SwiftData_SwiftUI             0x3364 <redacted> + 744
27 CashflowBalanceSheet           0x3d354 closure #2 in closure #1 in closure #1 in RootContentView.body.getter + 3 (@__swiftmacro_20CashflowBalanceSheet15RootContentViewV13activeplayers5QueryfMa_.swift:3)
28 CashflowBalanceSheet           0x3c414 closure #1 in closure #1 in RootContentView.body.getter + 116 (RootContentView.swift:116)
29 CashflowBalanceSheet           0x3bf4c closure #1 in RootContentView.body.getter + 122 (RootContentView.swift:122)
30 SwiftUICore                    0xbb31c <redacted> + 64
...

The lines referenced in the crash don't line up with any code that is related to the @Query. I checked previous versions of the code in the repo and the previous version had line 116 line up with a usage of activeplayers, but 122 did not.
Here's a stripped down version of the file, I removed stuff that didn't reference the @Query var at all:
struct RootContentView: View {
    // some other @State vars
    
    @Query(filter: #Predicate<Player> {
        $0.isshown == true
    }) var activeplayers: [Player]
    
    func checkifgameshouldbeshown() {
        // Handle the dismissing action.
        print("checkifgameshouldbeshown active players count: \(activeplayers.count)")
        if let player = self.activeplayers.first {
            if player.isshown {
                self.showinggame = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                // some views that don't use activeplayers
                
                VStack(spacing: 30) {
                    
                    // other stuff                      
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.activeplayers.forEach { player in
                            player.isshown = false
                        }
                        showingprofessionpicker.toggle()
                        
                    }) {
                        Image("button_new_sheet")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .padding(.horizontal, geometry.size.width * 0.1)
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingprofessionpicker,
                           onDismiss: checkifgameshouldbeshown) {
                        
                        ProfessionPickerView(showingnewsheetviews: $showingprofessionpicker)
                    }
                           
                    Button(action: continuegame) {
                        Image("button_continue")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .padding(.horizontal, geometry.size.width * 0.1)
                    }
                    .disabled(activeplayers.count == 0)
                    .opacity( (activeplayers.count == 0) ? 0.5 : 1.0) // <--- equiv of line 116 in previous version of code

                }
                .padding(.all) // <--- equiv of line 116 in current code
                
            } // <--- equiv of line 122 in previous version of code
            
        } // <-- equiv of line 122 in current code
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showinggame, content: {
            GameView(player: activeplayers.first!)
        })
        .onAppear() {
            withoutAnimation {
                // this function doesn't create any Player objects
                createdefaultrecordsifneeded()
            }
            
            withAnimation {
                checkifgameshouldbeshown()
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

Is there a way I can properly track down where the crash is happening so I can figure out how to fix it?

How does crashlytics work when you have a macro in your code? Does the lines match better if you expand the macro?

@JoakimDanielson I'm not sure which macro you are referring to. Is the the #Predicate? I don't know how to expand that, I'm not sure what swiftui/swiftdata is doing with it.

I am talking about the Query macro and you can right click it to expand it

@JoakimDanielson Ah, I see what you mean, and I think I'm starting to understand that line in the stacktrace: RootContentView.body.getter + 3 (@__swiftmacro_20CashflowBalanceSheet15RootContentViewV13activeplayers5QueryfMa_.swift:3)
When I expand the macro, it actually shows new line numbers within the macro, so it doesn't help me match up the overall lines, but that line in the stack trace that references the macro says it's line 3 within the macro. Which is the getter for that property:  get {         _activeplayers.wrappedValue } and the crash is on the .wrappedValue line.
